# HP LaserJet Pro 400 Color M451dn Phantom Print Jobs

Tags: windows-7, printer, hp-laserjet

**Scenario**: Multiple printers hooked up to a printer server (2008r2) including this HP LaserJet Pro 400 Color M451dn.  All machines that are using the printer are based on Windows 7 Enterprise x64.

**Problem**:  Every couple of days the users who frequent this printer let me know that a few dozen pages with random characters down one side of the paper print out.  This happens usually during the evening when no one is around to send print jobs to it.

**What I have done**: Provided the below screen shot of the printer log with what I assume is the print jobs in question.  I have looked into the printer driver compatibility and found no issues.

**Question**:  Is there a known issue with this printer or similar printers, and is there a solution that people are familiar with when they see multiple pages of gibberish printing out?

[image]

Comment: screenshot of the actual phantom print would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A firmware update seems to have fixed the error for this printer.